# How to find the right xpath for a link in menu?

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, xml-parsing, selenium-webdriver

I want to find right xpath for the following.

1. Open "http://in.jobsdb.com/in" site,
2. Then click on All job functions link.
3. Need xpath to click on 'Information Technology (IT)' link.

Here I tried the below and worked fine:

```
"//*[@id='searchbox-jfunc-priOptionContain']/menu/div/div/li[11]/a"
```

Here 11 is like hardcoded, if the position changes, then it will fail.
At the same time I don't want to use id, as if the id got changed it will fail.

So I need generic xPath, as I pass the technology name as an argument say "Insurance", or "Management".

And also it can be great if you can tell the xPath for selecting any of the sub technologies displayed like "DBA", "IT Auditing" which are all Listboxes in a sub menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match based on the text content of the `a` element using something like

```
//*[@id='searchbox-jfunc-priOptionContain']/menu/div/div/li/a[. = 'Insurance']
```

Or possibly `..../a[contains(., 'Insurance')]` if it's not an exact match.

Comment: I tried both of the below with no luck. WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='searchbox-jfunc-priOptionContain']/menu/div/div/li[*]/a[text()='Insurance']")); WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='searchbox-jfunc-priOptionContain']/menu/div/div/li[*]/contains(.,'Insurance')"));

Comment: @user1690506 neither of those are what I suggested.  Try `[. = 'Insurance']` or `[span = 'Insurance']` instead of `[text() = 'Insurance']`, since the "Insurance" text node is not a direct child of the `a` (it's under a nested `span`)

Comment: @user1690506 it's very rare that you actually need to use `text()` in an XPath expression.  `foo/text()` _doesn't_ mean "the text of `foo`" but rather "the set of individual text nodes that are direct children of `foo`".  You only need `text()` if you genuinely do need to treat each text node individually rather than looking at the complete text content under a particular element.

Comment: Sorry Ian, while referring some sites i observed text() is same as "." so tried that. But now it is working fine.

Comment: What does it mean "." in the above expression?

Comment: @Uday `.` means the current context node (in this case the `a` element that the predicate is filtering), so `. = 'Insurance'` is a test to check whether the string value of the current node is equal to the string "Insurance".  The string value of an element node is defined to be the concatenation of the text in all its descendant text nodes in document order (i.e. those text nodes that are direct children of the context node but also those that are more deeply nested in child elements, etc.).

Comment: @Uday conversely `text() = 'Insurance'` would test whether there is any _single_ text node that is a direct child of the context node and whose value is "Insurance".  That won't find anything in this case because you have `<a class="nav-item"><span>Insurance</span></a>` - the "Insurance" text node is not a child of the `a` element, it's a grandchild inside the `span`.  The string value of both the `a` and the `span` elements is "Insurance".

Answer (score 0):

`//a[span='Information Technology (IT)']` ------ to select "Information Technology (IT)" link

`//label[span='DBA']/input` ------------ To select "DBA" check box